# c# - Copy only selected data to new datatable with linq

Tags: c#, linq, select, datatable, group-by

I've searched the web for quite some time now and can't seem to find an elegant way to

- read data from one datatable,
- group it by two variables with linq
- select only those two variables (forget about the others in the source datatable) and
- copy these items to a new datatable.

I got it working without selecting specific variables, but at the amount of data the program is going to process later I'd rather only copy what's really needed.

```
var temp123 = from row in oldDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              orderby row["Column1"] ascending
              group row by new { Column1 = row["Column1"], Column2 = row["Column2"] } into grp
              select grp.First();

newDataTable = temp123.CopyToDataTable();
```

Can anyone please be so kind to help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use `CopyToDataTable` on an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`, only with `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. You need to create a new DataTable manually and use a loop to fill it with the result of this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom implementation of CopyToDataTable method from this article [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
newDataTable = 
    oldDataTable
       .AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new { Column1 = row["Column1"], Column2 = row["Column2"] })
       .Select(g => g.First())
       .OrderBy(x => x.Column1)
       .CopyToDataTable(); // your custom extension
```

Another option, as Tim suggested - manual creation of DataTable.

```
var newDataTable = new DataTable();
newDataTable.Columns.Add("Column1");
newDataTable.Columns.Add("Column2");

foreach(var item in temp123)
    newDataTable.Rows.Add(item.Column1, item.Column2);
```

And last option (if possible) - don't use DataTable - simply use collection of strongly typed objects.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I chose the second solution because a custom CopyToDataTable seems a bit out of proportion for my needs, I guess. ;)